# How do I get an image from an external site using RSS?

Tags: 8, feeds

I used the Aggregation module to consume news from an external RSS, but the pictures are not showing up.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use feeds and views rewrite result

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very limited information, but I think you are looking for something that shows images in News Aggregation Block, which is not a default feature.

You have to do some tweaking like mentioned [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2012-04-18/aggregator-block-how-to-show-pictures#comment-12554931) a Solution proposed by Shamseer.ch 
I hope they make this a feature soon.